# How should I use Task When All?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, async-await

I've got the follow code, I just need to make sure this is the correct way to do this.. It works and everything but isn't as quick as Id expect.. I've timed each individual call and the longest is no where near the time it takes it takes to run.

```
public async Task<Result[]> DoSomethingGoodAsync()
{
    List<Product> productList = getproducts();

    IEnumerable<Task<Result>> list = 
        from p in productList select DoSomethingAsync(p);

    Task<Result>[] slist = list.ToArray();

    return await Task.WhenAll(slist);
}
```

Now my question again, is this correct? Is there a better and more efficient way to do this? DoSomethingAsync is an awaitable method also which calls another async method.

Edit: My question.. Is this the correct way to build up a collection of awaitable methods that I want to execute together?

Inside DoSomethingAysnc()

```
   scrapeResult = await UrlScraper.ScrapeAsync(product.ProductUrl);

   model = this.ProcessCheckStock(model, scrapeResult, product);
```

Comment: Are you sure the time is not being taken up by the call to getproducts(); at the start?

Comment: What does `getproducts` look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that `getproducts` returns a type assignable to [`IList<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx).  This means that `getproducts` materializes the result set before you call `DoSomethingAsync` on each item returned from `getproducts`.

Depending on how long it takes to yield each item and materialize the set is more than likely having the most impact.

That said, you should change the `getproducts` method to return an [`IEnumerable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx) implementation.  But you need to do more than change the return type, you need to remove the materialization (more than likely a call to [`ToList`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261.aspx)) and use [`yield`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/9k7k7cf0.aspx) instead.

Comment: all that GetProducts does is goes to the DB and fetches at most 5 products, I've looked at this and its always a very quick call

Comment: @Steoates Then what does `DoSomethingAsync` do?

Comment: DoSomethingAsync is basically just a url scrape which does abit of processing, which can take awhile sometime! hence the async/await work ive done to try and speed this up

Comment: @Steoates Depending on how you use `async`/`await` in `DoSomethingAsync`, it could very well have an impact.  Using `async` doesn't mean that you automatically go to another thread.  Can you post the complete code for `DoSomethingAsync`?

Comment: inside that is basicly 
                    scrapeResult = await UrlScraper.ScrapeAsync(product.ProductUrl);

                    model = this.ProcessCheckStock(model, scrapeResult, product);   ProcessCheckStock isnt async/await

Comment: @Steoates You need to update your question with all of this, btw.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18802/discussion-between-steoates-and-casperone)